# jquery UI library interfering with existing classes

Tags: jquery-ui

Ive just had added the jquery ui library to a web page.

It appears that without even calling any its functions, it manipulates an unrelated div element which coincidentally has the css class name '`accordion`'

This is really bad design imo, is this functionality by design?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `$(selector).accordion()` function it won't manipulate your DOM.
BUT because you have a `class="accordion"` applied on an element, and I assume that you have loaded the *jquery.ui.css* with the js too, the default 'accordion' styles will get applied on your elements.

Comment: You dont consider adding all the jquery ui classes needed to make the accordion control work manipulating the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rucsi, the odd thing is that the classes on the JQuery UI css file use the class name ui-accordion. Anyway, try removing the following lines from your jquery-ui.css file (it's named jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css by default):

```
/*
 * jQuery UI Accordion 1.8.8
 *
 * Copyright 2010, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#theming
 */
/* IE/Win - Fix animation bug - #4615 */
.ui-accordion { width: 100%; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 1px; zoom: 1; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix { display: inline; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active { border-bottom: 0 !important; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a { display: block; font-size: 1em; padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em; }
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 2.2em; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon { position: absolute; left: .5em; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 1em 2.2em; border-top: 0; margin-top: -2px; position: relative; top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; overflow: auto; display: none; zoom: 1; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active { display: block; }/*
```